# Module Object is not Callable, using a PIR Sensor

Tags: python, sensors, omxplayer

I'm trying to build a Motion Detected play video for my store as a Welcome Introduction, so I'm using a PIR Sensor connected to the raspberry, and here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import sys

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
PIR_PIN=7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN,GPIO.IN)

def MOTION(PIR_PIN):
  os.sys("omxplayer -o local -b /home/pi/g1.mp4")

print("My Store Name")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Wating for Customers...")

try:
GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=MOTION)
while 1:
        time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("Quit")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

My problems comes once the sensors detect a movement, a video should have to be played, but I got the error message: **'Module'object is not callable**

Any clue?

Thanks in Advance, Im will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried adding `pass` after `except KeyboardInterrupt:`? (indented of course)

Comment: Did you meant to use `os.system` (instead of `os.sys`)?

Comment: thanks for your comments, well Im using   `os.sys` as a Run Time Services, but should I have to use:

    `os.system(omxplayer -o local -b g1.mp4)`